# eval вызывается в локальной области видимости?

Tags: javascript

```
global.a = 20;
var a = 10;

{
  let a = {};
  eval('a.member = 5');
}
```

Eval добавит свойство в объект a в этом же блоке? Или к глобальной?
Главный вопрос в том, что если несколько асинхронных функций будут вызывать такой eval, то не будут ли они работать с одной и той же глобальной переменной?

Comment: `global.a = 20;
var a = 10;` - это node.js?

Comment: @Qwertiy
да, это он

Comment: Тогда глобальная - это global. У var область видимости - модуль.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

- Прямой вызов `eval` - в локальной (с некоторыми оговорками).
- Непрямой в ES5+ - в глобальной.
- Непрямой в ES3 - любое поведение, в том числе бросание исключения.

```js
var x = {};

{
  let x = {};
  
  // локальный скоуп
  eval("x.a = 1");
  (eval)("x.b = 2");
  
  // глобальный скоуп
  (1,eval)("x.k = 16");
  window.eval("x.l = 17");
  const e = eval; e("x.m = 18");
  [eval][0]("x.n = 19");
  eval.call(null, "x.o = 20");
  
  console.log(x);
}

console.log(x);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Уточнения про локальную область видимости:

- Переменные, объявленные внутри `eval` через `let` и `const`, не появляются в текущем скоупе.
- Переменные, объявленные внутри `eval` через `var`, а также функции, объявленные через function declaration, появляются в текущем скоупе только в нестрогом режиме.

```js
~function () {
  eval("var a = 1");
  eval("let b = 2");
  eval("const c = 3");
  eval("function d() {}");
  
  console.log(typeof a, typeof b, typeof c, typeof d);
}();

~function () {
  'use strict';

  eval("var a = 1");
  eval("let b = 2");
  eval("const c = 3");
  eval("function d() {}");
  
  console.log(typeof a, typeof b, typeof c, typeof d);
}();
```

Comment: А что имеется ввиду
"Прямой вызов eval - в локальной (с некоторыми оговорками)."

Какие оговорки?

Comment: @manking, уже дополнил.

Comment: @manking, и ещё дополнил.

Comment: Про let странно. Получается когда eval вызывается, то он как бы создаёт блок {} внутри которого и вызывает код?

Comment: @manking, ну грубо можно так сказать. Но обращаю внимание на `var` в строгом режиме - его поведение блоком не объясняется. Хотя можно попробовать сказать типа блок в нестрогом и самовызывающаяся функция (хотя вряд ли - this и arguments же) в строгом. Но вообще, подозреваю, что устроено не так. В общем, лучше не мудрить с обобщениями.

Comment: А как нибудь можно сделать, чтобы eval дозволял обращение только к конкретной переменной локальной?  А то ведь там можно куда угодно из него обратиться.

Comment: @manking, а как насчёт `new Function`? И вообще, недоверенные данные не надо отправлять ни туда, ни туда. Ещё можно with Proxy присобачить, но это что-то жесть.